# Script dialogues

Tags: macros, formatting

I'm trying to write a script, and I have defined the following commands:

```
\newcommand{\SpeechText}[1]{
 \vbox{\ignorespaces{\quotation{#1}}\par\duplines}
}
\newcommand{\ParagraphText}[1]{
 %\paragraph{
    \vspace{0.2in}
    \vbox{\ignorespaces{#1}\par\duplines}
    \vspace{0.2in}
 %}
}
```

With them, I create a blur effect and a quote/paragraph style respectively.
When I use them in the following text

```
\chapter{\RED{Nocturno}}
%
\ParagraphText{text text text ... text text}
%
\SpeechText{aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa}
%
\SpeechText{bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb}
%
\SpeechText{cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc}
....
```

I get this error:

`LaTeX Error: Too deeply nested. [}]`

Can you help me? Additionally, I would like a left and right padding in the `\SpeechText` command. How can I get it?

Here is the whole code:

```
\documentclass[ms,a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

%\setstocksize{8.26in}{6.1in}
\settrimmedsize{8.26in}{6.1in}*
\fixpdflayout

\chapterstyle{dash} % try also reparticle
\usepackage{ulem}   % underline
\usepackage{xcolor} %
%\usepackage{lipsum} %dummy text
% All font size must be normal size 
\renewcommand{\large}{\normalsize}
\renewcommand{\Large}{\normalsize}
\newcommand{\red}[1]{\textcolor{red!50!black}{#1}}
\newcommand{\RED}[1]{\textcolor{red!50!black}{\MakeUppercase{#1}}}
% font hyphenation 
\usepackage{everysel}
\EverySelectfont{%
    \fontdimen2\font=0.6em % interword space
    \fontdimen3\font=0.2em % interword stretch
    \fontdimen4\font=0.1em % interword shrink
    \fontdimen7\font=0.9em % extra space
    \hyphenchar\font=`\-% to allow hyphenation
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% Speech lines
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\SpeechText}[1]{%
    \vbox{\ignorespaces{\quotation{#1}}\par\duplines}
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% Paragraph lines
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\ParagraphText}[1]{%
        \vspace{0.2in}%
        \vbox{\ignorespaces{#1}\par\duplines}%
        \vspace{0.2in}%
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Nocturno}

\ParagraphText{
            Las enormes gafas de sol apenas pueden ocultar su cara destrozada, 
            la cicatriz desde casi el lacrimal del ojo hasta la comisura del lado derecho 
            de la boca. Sonríe. Y los dientes que le faltan convierten su boca en un abismo, 
            un agujero negro tragador de materia oscura. 
}

\SpeechText{
            No es bueno contradecir al jefe
}

\SpeechText{
            Ese Jefe no es mi Jefe
}

.....


\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide the full LaTeX source of your input.

Comment: Your "full" example does not generate the error you say, it generates `! Undefined control sequence.
\ParagraphText ...ignorespaces {#1}\par \duplines ` If I add the definition from the accepted answer on the question referenced by Andrea L. it runs without error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't given any indication of what you want your commands to do, or given an example input that generates the error however

```
\newcommand{\SpeechText}[1]{
 \vbox{\ignorespaces{\quotation{#1}}\par\duplines}
}
```

You are missing `%` at the ends of lines so this will introduce space tokens into your document. The `\ignorespaces` does nothing as it just ignores space tokens until the first non-space token is encountered but you follow it immediately by `{`.  `\vbox` is not really a latex command at this level, if you need a box at all? You probably want `\parbox`. `\quotation` is the internal command for the `quotation` environment and if used in that form it needs a matching `\endquotation`. `\duplines` I can't comment on. as you have shown no definition.

Comment: Maybe it is remotely related to [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36552/blur-the-text-so-its-not-readable), and if that's the case, removing the `\RED` (which I think is a red-uppercase only text) it compiles without errors to me...