# Generate unreadable handwriting text

Tags: fonts

I read this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36552/blur-the-text-so-its-not-readable), not what I want, I don't want lorem ipsum either

see this picture

[image]

A classic movie scene in cartoons and real movies, a letter appears to be written in a smooth elegant handwriting. However, the text itself is meaningless. Lots of curves. The reader immediately understands that it's unreadable so he skips to the end of the letter to read the readable part.

maybe something like

[image]

or this

[image]

Can such text be generated using latex? Many people try to read lorem ipsum, including me :) if i mix alphabet letters, the reader might not be able to spot the readable part immediately, and might ignore the whole article. I want to avoid using alphabet letters, and I want handwriting since it's smooth.

Comment: You could use [a font from this package](http://ctan.org/pkg/tolkienfonts) or one of the archaic scripts shown in the comprehensive list of LaTeX symbols, perhaps. Or [hacm](http://ctan.org/pkg/hacm)?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

first hit for google squiggle fonts suggested http://www.fontspace.com/category/squiggle from where I picked up MumbleGrumble (free for personal use licence) then using xelatex:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{MumbleGrumble I BB}

\begin{document}

One two three four this is almost as bad as my real handwriting.
Red yellow green blue.


\end{document}
```

Comment: I didn't know that this kind of writing is called squiggle, not a native english speaker, otherwise i would have googled it too :) I'm a fluent speaker but there are always words that you just don't know, no matter how good you are :) a native speaker will always know more words :)   thank you

Comment: btw i'm a native arabic speaker and i don't know what squiggle is in arabic and i'm a francophone and i don't know it in french either :)

Comment: @Fischer: Squiggle is "a short, irregular curve or twist, as in writing or drawing" according to http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/squiggle.  Here's samples: https://www.google.com/search?q=squiggle&tbm=isch

Comment: thanks for letting me know, I remembered the word in arabic, for french, i had to use google translate :)

Comment: @Fischer sorry I didn't mean to imply you should have found it yourself, but I wanted to highlight that it was a random google search result not not an actual font recommendation.

Comment: i understood what you meant :) and I'm thankful that you highlighted that fact, I learnt a new word, and I now I know that I can find many squiggles using google and I can find many awesome fonts on the site you linked to :)

Comment: It looks exactly like my mum's handwriting. `:)`

Comment: @PauloCereda So, what does it say?

Comment: @Clint: I have no idea. `:)`