Generate unreadable handwriting text with PDFLaTeX
I´m looking for a way of simulating unreadable writing text exactly as is descrbied in
Generate unreadable handwriting text
but for compile with PDFLaTeX.

Is this possible?

you could convert the font, or just draw the squigles with tikz but why the pdftex requirement why not simply use luatex?

Obviously the easiest way is to first generate a PDF consist of the squiggles with LuaLaTeX then includegraphics it in.

@DavidCarlisle Because I like the mathpazo font (\usepackage{mathpazo}) and the similar font, Gyre, for LuaTex is a little thinner in any letters.

@user202729 Yes, I wopuld prefer another solution, if exists, because is for generate some images using parameters.

This question asked for irregular lines https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/732884/245790 . In the comments you find many links to ragged lines.

Please EDIT your question and clarify, if you want a font, some (Tikz) graphics, and: what your use case is. Thank you

is it OK if elves can read it, so long as most humans can't?

@MS-SPO exactly as it´s describd at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/218297/generate-unreadable-handwriting-text I prefer a 'unreadable font' as the solution  \usepackage{fontspec} \setmainfont{MumbleGrumble I BB} but if it´s no possible, I´m using yout solution with Irregular/Ragged Lines. If you answer, I would close acceptiing your solution as the solution.

Ok ... do you mean repeating my comment(s) as answer?
