# How do I make a presentation that seems made on an overhead projector?

Tags: typography, presentations, fun

I want to do a presentation simulating an overhead projector which some professors used when I was a math student.

I couldn't find an image to mimic the background produced by an overhead projector. Also I was trying to make the text a little blurry using this: [Blur the text so it's not readable](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36552/blur-the-text-so-its-not-readable), but it would be better if the entire document (background and images) is a little blurry and yellowish. I'm using a different font to simulate handmade annotations (http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Permanent+Marker).

Being more specific:

- Background produced by an overhead projector.
- Blurry and yellowish document.
- Handmade annotations across the text.

Edit: 
Minimal example without text blur

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pages=all]{background}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{color}
\newfontfamily\myfont[Scale=2.5]{PermanentMarker}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\backgroundsetup{
opacity=0.4,
angle=0,
contents={%
\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{background-image}
}%
}

\usepackage[overlay,absolute]{textpos}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-5]
\begin{textblock}{5}(6,6)
    {\myfont {\color{blue} Some annotations}}
\end{textblock}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: It might be easier to create normal slides with LaTeX and then use imagemagick, gimp, or other image manipulation tool to create the border, blur, and yellowed looks.  Note that imagemagick is command line driven, so you could do all of this work with a batch file.

Comment: The text would not be blurry if the projector was working and adjusted correctly. Colour distortion is another case but since LCD projection also distorts, but differently, you are going to have fake distortion + non-faked distortion of a different kind interacting. (Some distortion I've seen in LCD projection outstrips anything an overhead projector could do by an order of magnitude.)

Comment: 1. Purchase yellow overhead transparency, 2. lightly sand the transparency to produce some scratches, and 3. tape the transparency over the LCD projector lens. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to @James comment I tried an imagemagick approach to answer my own question.

This is a small example (compiled with XeLaTeX), Google Permanent marker font is needed (http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Permanent+Marker)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{color}
\newfontfamily\myfont[Scale=2.5]{PermanentMarker}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage[overlay,absolute]{textpos}

\begin{document}
\begin{textblock}{8}(4,6)
    {\myfont {\color{blue} Some annotations...}}
\end{textblock}
\blindmathpaper
\blindmathpaper
\begin{textblock}{8}(2,8)
    {\myfont {\color{blue} More annotations...}}
\end{textblock}
\end{document}
```

For the imagemagick part I used Color filter script from (http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/colorfilter/index.php)

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -ne 2 ] ; then
   echo -e "You  must specify two parameters: filename and corner option s (square) or r (round)."
   exit 1
fi

if [ ! -f $1 ]; then
    echo "File not found!"
    exit 1
fi

if [ "$2" != "s" ] && [ "$2" != "r" ] ; then
   echo "Error in corner option, must be s or r"
   exit 1
fi

output="op_$1"
convert -density 200 $1 -quality 00 -background white -alpha remove page-%d.png

for img in `ls page-*.png`
do
if [ $2 == "s" ]
then
convert $img\
        \( -size 300x200 xc:none -draw "fill black polygon 0,0 0,200 200,0" \
       -write mpr:triangle  +delete \) \
        \( mpr:triangle             \) -gravity northwest -composite \
        \( mpr:triangle -flip       \) -gravity southwest -composite \
        \( mpr:triangle -flop       \) -gravity northeast -composite \
        \( mpr:triangle -rotate 180 \) -gravity southeast -composite \
        $img
fi
if [ $2 == "r" ]
then
convert $img \
        \( +clone -alpha extract \
           -draw 'fill black polygon 0,0 0,300 300,0 fill white circle 300,300 300,0' \
        \( +clone -flip \) -compose Multiply -composite \
        \( +clone -flop \) -compose Multiply -composite \
        \) -alpha off -compose CopyOpacity -composite -compose \
        over -background black -flatten \
        $img
fi
./colorfilter -m 1 -c warming81 -d 45 $img $img
convert $img -blur 3x1 $img
done

convert page*.png -gravity center $output
rm -f page*.png
```

Please feel free to correct or improve my answer.

Edit: Screenshot added.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: A screenshot would be nice !

Comment: Now the only thing short is to make it a bit blurry, (because the teacher did not tighten the screw enough, which holds the mirror and it is slowly sliding down while he is talking and explaining...) Hahaha this is nice.