# How to blur a single word?

Tags: texmaker

I would like to blur a single word within a pagraph.

I've read this : [Blur the text so it's not readable](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36552/blur-the-text-so-its-not-readable) 
but it applies to a whole paragraph (thus not working on a sigle word without a line break and vertical paragraph separation spaces).

Comment: did you have a look at the answer by [Martin Brandenburg in the post you linked to?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/291257/89976)? It should work for single words.

Comment: Depending if the goal is to "blur" or to "make unreadable", the `censor` package may be of use.  A question you must ask yourself is what should happen if one applies copy/paste to the blurred PDF text.  Some methods might provide "un-blurred" copy/paste capability.

Comment: if it really *is* only one word, you might be able to pack that word in a box and just blur the contents of the box.  it should still take the same amount of space horizontally, which is what matters.  wouldn't work, of course, if it happened to fall at the end of a line and needed to be hyphenated.