# How to blur covered elements in Beamer instead of making them invisible or transparent

Tags: beamer

Default behavior of Beamer for covered elements is to make them invisible. You can change this to making them transparent by

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
% desired command to blur instead
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    \pause
    \lipsum[1]
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

However, I regularly have questions whose answer is covered and appears in the next overlay. People in the audience can then still see enough of the answer.
I don't want to make covered elements invisible, because it helps me as a presenter to have an indication of how much more material there is on the slide.
The degree of transparency can be controlled, but I don't think there is a level that solves my problem.

Hence my desire to blur covered elements. Is there a way to accomplish this in Beamer (easily)?

This question is about blurring words: [How to blur a single word?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/327420/how-to-blur-a-single-word), but I don't see how to use that in Beamer as an option to `\setbeamercovered`. Another blurring technique for text is discussed in this question: [Blur the text so it's not readable](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36552/blur-the-text-so-its-not-readable/), but again I don't know how to use it in Beamer.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the fantastic answer https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=6276#a6152 by @Skillmon, you could censor the still covered text:

```
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex

\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\usepackage{lua-ul}
\usepackage{luacolor}


\ExplSyntaxOn
\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand \magic {O{\l__luaul_highlight_color_tl}} {
  \@highLight [#1]
}
\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOff

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\beamer@startcovered}{\color{.}}{\color{.}\magic[.]}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}[t]
    \uncover<+->{}
    \uncover<+->{\lipsum[2]}
    \begin{itemize}[<+->]
    \item test
    \item test
    \end{itemize}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank for the suggestion, but this fails to answer my question in a couple of ways: (1) If this is done to only a few words, then one can still see the `covered' answer; (2) it does not apply globally to all covered items; (3) when items are uncovered, they need to be normally visible.