# Get certified in TeX/LaTeX

Tags: latex-misc

I was wondering if there are any ways to get certified in TeX/LaTeX?
This would be useful, e.g. for providing a way of quantifying the expertise someone has with TeX, LaTeX or other TeX flavors.

Comment: As there is no such a certificate, the best and effective way to convince others that we have (La)TeX skill is by showing your achievements on our own blog, for example by writing many articles, accomplishing many production projects, showing your seminar videos, etc.

Comment: It would be interesting to know how many people would be like to get certified. I don'd see such a big demand.

Answer (score 20):

AFAIK there is no official certificate. You may get one from a lecturer or a school when you participated in a course.

It would be nice if there was something comparable to the Linux certificate, with certain levels such as:

- L1: is able to use the most important document classes and has a good understanding of packages
- L2: Is hardcore LaTeX kernel developer.

Well, there should probably be a few more levels.

Answer (score 19):

It's nothing official, but you could point people to your profile here at tex.sx. Reputation is *TeX knowledge quantified, if you want to put it this way. You could use your [flair](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/10635/digital-ink/flair) as well or point to the percentile your belong to, which is in your case currently "top 16% this week", I'm "top 5% overall", egreg is "top 0.09% overall" = No.1. You find this information in the reputation box on your profile summary. Here's your flair:

[image: profile for digital-Ink at TeX - LaTeX, Q&A for users of TeX, LaTeX, ConTeXt, and related typesetting systems]

One way or the other, I'm sure people would believe [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg) that he knows his way around *TeX if he showed them his profile/flair: `:)`

[image: profile for egreg at TeX - LaTeX, Q&A for users of TeX, LaTeX, ConTeXt, and related typesetting systems]

Going further (and further abusing egreg as an example), [tags](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg?tab=tags) actually provide an overview of a user's fields of expertise, even though these are also highly dependent on what users ask about. The same applies for [tag badges](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg?tab=badges&sort=class) (listed before the regular badges, distinguishable through the different background color).

Stack Overflow actually took this concept a step further with [Stack Overflow Careers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/), where users can create a profile combining personal information with stats from their SO profile.

While tex.sx is certainly not yet as big in the *TeX world as SO seems to be in the programming world, I have a feeling it's steadily growing in importance, as we are gaining more and more highly knowledgeable and well-known experts as members and as regular contributors.

---

Responding to some of the comments:

Reputation is not a negative indicator of knowledge, i.e. low rep doesn't mean a person is not knowledgeable; but beyond a certain amount of rep (perhaps 10k or 20k at the moment) you can be quite confident that a user has a thorough understanding of some fields and principles of the *TeX world. Of course activity plays an important role, and so does the popularity of the topic you're answering about, but these may be regarded cornerstones of this "certification": "Normal" certificates may require you to spend a certain number of hours in class or on a project (= activity on tex.sx); the relative popularity of a certain topic reflects the (admittedly potentially irrational) relevance that the tex.sx community assigns to that topic. There still is a lot of inaccuracy and randomness going on -- I wouldn't think [Cthulu worshipping madmen](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29402/4012) play a major role in daily *TeXing, as the rep gained from that question might imply -- but isn't that the case with certificates and standardized tests as well (I think that's the point that @Brent was making)?

Comment: Reputation doesn't represent knowledge, though.  It represents how active you are in the online community.

Comment: For example one can get lots of reputation in the ConTeXt area and know little about LaTeX.

Comment: On the whole reputation on this site is a rather funny beast - the total is directly linked to activity (not necessary quality) and even the individual votes are more  than often strange; so even a "reputation divided by (answers+questions)" does not necessarily give much clarity about the qualification of the person.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Certification doesn't represent knowledge, either, but is a cheap (expensive?) plastic substitute for experience. It's just another way half-witted "managers" try to measure the unmeasurable -- a person's worth, and, IMNSHO, tends to propagate unthinking mediocrity. Although it's not perfect, reputation is a direct assessment of your usefulness to other people.

Comment: @Ben & Co.: See my edit.

Comment: @BenVoigt I endorse Brent's opinion. I would add also that reputation is gained both from good answers *and* good questions: asking good questions is as useful as answering.

Comment: @Brent: Perhaps it's better here than on the SO main site, but over there, people get votes and even accepted answers for stuff that sounds good, even when it's totally wrong (and a simple trip to the compiler shows that).  Combine that with a lot of time on the site, the cost carried by downvoting this garbage and limited effect of downvotes, and you end up with people prolific enough in deceptive answers to have 10k privileges.  (And sometimes these answers involve "urban legends", where a majority of users actually believe the wrong answer)

Comment: For an example, many thousands of rep points have been given out on SO for the explanation that "in C# (or .Net) unboxed value types are always stored on the call stack".  Nevermind that it's not true.  On the other hand, @Brent makes a good point about the quality of certifications -- some of them will award points for this same wrong knowledge (and deduct for right answers).

Comment: @BenVoigt: I think you're right in that the SE system works better here than on SO, which I think is due to the more limited amount of questions as well as topics on tex.sx compared to SO.

Comment: I based my outburst, admittedly, on my experience principally here on TeX.SX, and my "areas of interest" on SO, which include Python and Haskell and one or two legacy things, but not C#, .Net, or Java. Is it just an impression that these latter languages are slightly closer to the world of certification?

Comment: @Brent: They're more popular in the corporate world, certainly, which tends to attract people who sell certification (of both the semi-useful and diploma mill varieties).  But I'd be quite surprised if there weren't an equal number of widely-believed-but-wrong "urban legends" concerning Python and Haskell.