# Is there any certificate that confirms the level of knowledge of TeX, LaTeX?

Tags: cv

I would like to know, is there any certificate that confirms the level of knowledge of TeX, LaTeX (like level of English -- B2), couse I want to add it to my CV.

Comment: Yes, your reputation on TeX.SE.

Comment: And may be some besides?

Comment: None that I know of. I don’t think there is. TeX knowledge is not something that is usually tested anywhere. Perhaps there are universities in the world where they give courses in TeX, but that’s probably the closest you get. The TeX community is rather small and is mostly centred around this site.

Comment: Duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/56548/15036 ?

Comment: I have listed on my CV that I am proficient in LaTeX, without any proof. People usually believe that :)

Comment: Ok thak all of You for answering my question

Comment: The certificate for the beginner's course can be claimed after successfully de-obfuscating [`xii.tex`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/plain/contrib/xii/xii.tex), and for the advanced course after rewriting `xii.tex` with in 50% fewer tokens :)

Comment: Why would anyone claim LaTeX experience if they didn't have it?  It would be a rare employer who would even know what LaTeX is, much less be impressed.

Comment: TeX output could be a demonstration of TeX skills or knowledge (or of Googling ability). Although, by the design of things, deep mastery of TeX would not be visible on the page to a reader (although, again, *non*-mastery would be *totally* visible).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is not. The closest thing to it was a certificate given to people who completed classes offered by TUG back when they still offered classes and, to be honest, everyone who showed up for the class got one (although at least for the classes I taught, I did everything I could to make sure that they left knowing the basics of LaTeX, or for the one class on creating LaTeX classes, that they could do basic (and some involved) class design).