# What is best way to mention that a document has been typeset with TeX?

Tags: typography, best-practices, latex-misc, teaching

Is there any common way to mention that a document has been typeset by TeX? So non-TeXnicians (TeXperts) may become a little familiar with the TeX world.

**Update**: It would be nice if one hero make a package that inserts such information in beauty and concise manner in a given language, so even lazy TeXnicians will credit TeX. For example:

```
...
\usepackage{colophon}
...
\colophon[language=fa,packages=bibtex,xepersian]
...
```

Comment: I know this might sound odd, but IMHO documents typeset in TeX speak for themselves. `:)` I recently created a song booklet for my parish and everybody was amazed by the quality! People came to me and asked how I made "Word produce such beautiful documents"; then I gently explained about TeX and friends. `:)`

Comment: @PauloCereda: could you show me the song booklet?

Comment: @HiggsBoson: Sure! `:)` [Here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/7zufo.jpg) is an image from the PDF and [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/cVA29.jpg) is the real booklet (sorry for the quality). I took a minimalist approach because we had to put as many songs as possible. This document basically relies on `multicol`, `lettrine` and `xcolor`. `:)`

Comment: @HiggsBoson: Thanks for the kind words. `:)` [This one](http://i.stack.imgur.com/nP8K0.jpg) is a songsheet we did for St. Joseph's mass; the document relies on the `songs` package. `:)`

Comment: @HiggsBoson: I have no idea. `:)` Let's wait and see, SE already loves me for being a serial voter. `:P`

Comment: @Reza: How much will you pay to that hero?

Comment: @PauloCereda Beautiful. Would love to learn TeX after seeing that now.

Comment: @Abu-Lu'lu'ahal-Nahawandi Heroes do not accept remuneration! ;)

Comment: @PauloCereda It looks very nice! So simple and yet it stands out. It is a proof of the point you have made earlier.

Comment: @PauloCereda: Why don't you add this to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1319/showcase-of-beautiful-typography-done-in-tex-friends? It's always nice to see contributions there that aren't academic theses. Plus I love seeing TeXed documents actually printed, they usually look even better than on screen.

Comment: @Reza: are you a hero?

Comment: @doncherry Yours is ccepted! `;)`

Comment: @PauloCereda The people in your parish must be either very sensitive to good design or awfully accustomed to very bad design; I can't imagine anybody I know making remarks about the appearance of any document, except me.

Comment: @marczellm: I suspect it's the second option. `:)` There are some really terrible designs around here. `:)`

Comment: @marczelim: Hahaha, I so feel the same!

Comment: I didn't test yet, but https://ctan.org/pkg/colophon?lang=en

Answer (score 78, accepted):

TeXies have a good chance of recognizing TeXed documents, especially if Computer Modern (or Latin Modern) is used. But assuming you want to convert Word-users and other heathens, figuratively speaking, you could use a [colophon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colophon_%28publishing%29), a "brief description of publication or production notes relevant to the edition, in modern books usually located at the reverse of the title page, but can also sometimes be located at the end of the book" (Wikipedia). Some of the theses listed at [Showcase of beautiful typography done in TeX & friends](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1319/showcase-of-beautiful-typography-done-in-tex-friends) have such notes:

> This thesis was typeset using the LaTeX typesetting system originally developed by Leslie Lamport, based on TeX created by Donald Knuth.

([Eivind Uggedal](http://www.duo.uio.no/publ/informatikk/2008/81971/uggedal.pdf))

> Typeset by the author in Fedra Serif B using LaTeX. Cover design by Sam Ross-Gower.

([Michael Ummels](http://logic.rwth-aachen.de/~ummels/diss.pdf))

And here's a particularly pretty one:

[image: Colophon. This document was created using LaTeX2ε and BibTeX and edited in the Mac-Vim environment with the LaTeX-vim plug-in. The typesettings software used the XeTeX distribution and the fontspec package. The text is set in Hoefler Text and Candara. The source code is set in Consolas. The animal depicted on the cover is a common eland (taurotragus oryx). The original photograph was taken from flickr.com/photos/paulmullett/505797443/ and is used and modified with permission under the Creative Commons “by-nc” license. The author of the original picture is Paul Mullett.]

([Konrad Rudolph](http://madrat.net/my/bachelor/thesis))

Here's another cool one from [*The Book of Tea*](http://mysite.verizon.net/william_franklin_adams/portfolio/typography/thebookoftea.pdf) by Okakura Kazuko as typeset by [William Adams](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/31151/willadams). Part of this book can be found as [an example of TeX typography](http://www.tug.org/texshowcase/partofTheBookofTea.pdf)  in the [TeX showcase](http://www.tug.org/texshowcase/#text).

[image: Colophon. Typeset in Octavian, by David Kindersley. by Dr. Donald Knuth’s TeX system. Printed on Crane’s Crest paper. with a NeXT Laserprinter. by an ’040 NeXT Cube. Converted to .pdf. by pStill.app.]

If you actually want to get people started by your notes (and not just potentially curious), I'd point them to Tobias Oetiker's 
[The Not So Short Introduction to LaTeX2ε](http://tobi.oetiker.ch/lshort/lshort.pdf), and – obviously – to tex.sx.

Comment: Beat me by a few seconds, nice answer :)

Comment: I wish this were still common. I've read several books recently where I wish I knew what typeface they were using! I know I could take a picture and upload it to this or that site, but just having the info in the book would be great.

Comment: Regarding that bachelors thesis: it is really nice looking. But better use the `ccions` package.

Comment: What's the `ccions` package, what is it good for, and why is it not coming up on google?

Comment: oh, I meant `ccicons`. This is not directly related to the original question. Just noticed the ugly creative commons symbols there.

Comment: how can i have the font used in the colophon for "fontspec"  ? thanks

Comment: @FormlessCloud: I'd suggest asking Konrad Rudolph that question at the post in which he presented his thesis: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1474/4012. If the solution turns out to be interesting, make it a new question! (I'd assume that it's just some font used with XeLaTeX and accessing stylistic variants, though.)

Answer (score 22):

Here's an angle: Don't do anything. Instead, have a look at the PDF information (in case of PDF output), in this example, Preview.app's cmd+i -window (sorry for the localization, but I hope you get the idea):

[image]

Et voilà, unobtrusive and simple.

Comment: This is interesting for people who want to find out how the document was produced, but I think the OP is looking for a way really to put the info about LaTeX in people's faces. Also, this information is "lost" when printing.

Comment: @doncherry: true that. Though, who said anything about LaTeX?

Comment: I prefer to say "LaTeX" for _marketing_ reasons, because it makes people curious [what kind of a kinky thing](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29402/how-do-i-make-my-document-look-like-it-was-written-by-a-cthulhu-worshipping-madm/29458#comment57793_29402) is going on there ... `;)`

Comment: @doncherry: Hahah, I see `:)`

Answer (score 14):

First of all: it seems a good idea to mention somewhere "Document typeset with LaTeX". Because your readers may realise that this is a well typeset document, but may have no clue how it has been produced.

Where you mention your machinery surely depends on your document. In a book the acknowledgements are the place to mention LaTeX or whatever. I a report maybe on the last page or the last footnote in smaller print? This seems a question of taste.

Comment: It is not really `LaTeX` that typesets it; it is your TeX engine that typesets it. LaTeX is just a bunch of macros like any other package.

Comment: @Abu-Lu'lu'ahal-Nahawandi I disagree, your honor: If you were informed "typeset by TeX", you'd have to figure out by yourself whether it was LaTeX or ConTeX or whatever. But it's LaTeX which consists of a kernel, thousands of packages and a lively community. "LaTeX" is the helpfull piece of information to people who never have heard of anything but Wörd.

Comment: Neither `LaTeX` nor `ConTeXt`  by themselves can typeset anything for you; it is the underlying TeX engine that typeset it.

Comment: So if I use  `color` package to typeset a document, can I claim that `clor` package typeset that document? the answer is no since `color` package can not do anything on its own. It is a macro package that tells TeX what to do and it is TeX that actually typesets your document not `color` package.

Comment: `LaTeX` isn't a package. It's a format.

Comment: I know that `LaTeX` is a format but that does not make any difference. Both `LaTeX` and any `package` are some macros.

Comment: @Abu-Lu'lu'ahal-Nahawandi: The difference is that all that I -- as an end-user -- use is LaTeX. I say `latex thesis.tex`, not `tex thesis.tex`. It's like saying "I got here by car" instead of "I got here by combustion of gasoline". The fine difference might be saying "This document was typeset _with_ LaTeX" instead of "_by_ LaTeX".

Comment: @doncherry: LaTeX doesn't **typeset** anything, it's TeX that does all the work! (and, well, the output drivers, but you get the idea)

Comment: @morbusg: But couldn't you say "This letter was typeset _with_ the typewriter XYZ", even though eventually it was me who pushed down the keys (i.e. typeset _by_ me, _with_/using a certain tool)?

Comment: @doncherry: I don't think it's fruitful to start thinking of analogies here. It's just that, well, I think it's empathy that gets me all riled up when people say LaTeX (read: Leslie Lamport et co.) does this or that, when in fact it is TeX (read: Don Knuth) that does it.

Comment: TeX is the real engine and does all the real work. LaTeX is a (large) framework for TeX, normally dumped to a format. True, it's by far the most popular TeX environment, and it's the name many people know it by; but it's the paint, not the car. (Sorry for using an analogy, morbusg!) Keks and @doncherry, you probably use a GUI editor, but if you say "this document was typeset with Texshop", you're missing the point. Ditto for LaTeX. By all means mention LaTeX as well (and your GUI, why not), but if you leave TeX out, you're either sloppy or confused.

Comment: It would be very hard to mention `LaTeX` and leave out `TeX`. In `LaTeX`: A document preparation system` (section 1.3), Leslie Lamport writes "The `TeX` in `LaTeX` refers to Donald Knuth's `TeX` typesetting system."

Comment: Saying that LaTeX doesn't do the typesetting makes as much sense as saying that it's not the car that is driving from a to b but the engine/gas/tires/...

Comment: From the *LaTeX Companion* ("Production Notes"): "This book was typeset using the LaTeX document processing system.... The book was typset with the base LaTeX release dated 2003/12/01.  The pdfTeX program was used as the underlying engine, but it was not set to produce PDF output [because they wanted 'hanging punctuation' from the `pdfcprot` package]."  Also: I don't think many people use the `TeX` engine anymore; isn't it almost always `pdfTeX`, `LuaTeX`, or `XeTeX`?

Comment: @Abu-Lu'lu'ahal-Nahawandi -- I thought colour was a feature of the driver (e.g., `dvips`), not (plain) TeX.  Isn't that why plain TeX users are supposed to load `miniltx.tex` in order to use the `color` package..?

Answer (score 13):

1. Make the document as easy on the eye as possible. 
   This'll make people wonder what package you've used to produce it.
2. At the end of the document put a small - very brief - note in the bottom right corner :

   ```
      [LaTeX typeset]
   ```

Comment: Plainly that's for the other posters to judge not you or me. But I'd have thought that my reply was easier to absorb.

Answer (score 11):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\AtEndDocument{%
\begin{flushright}
    \sf\small This document was typeset by \href{http://tex.stackexchange.com}{\TeX}.
\end{flushright}}

\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: It is not really `LaTeX` that typesets it; it is your TeX engine that typesets it. LaTeX is just a bunch of macros like any other package.

Comment: @Abu-Lu'lu'ahal-Nahawandi I think the distinction between LaTeX and TeX is ridiculous. For a beginner, it is doing more harm than good (they start looking for TeX books such as the TeXbook) and for experts, well, they know the difference.

Comment: @Abu-Lu'lu'ahal-Nahawandi What about `this document was created with LaTeX`? I was already using LaTeX for a while when I noticed that people tend to use the word 'typesetting' here, and some more time until I started to have a faint idea about what it means. For an ordinary person there is no distinction IMO. This way we could stop this ridiculous discussion about TeX vs. LaTeX etc.. (Do I need the two periods here by the way? :-) )

Comment: @marczellm No, you don't. See http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8382/when-etc-is-at-the-end-of-a-phrase-do-you-place-a-period-after-it .

Comment: how about: `This document was typeset using the LaTeX document processing system originally developed by Leslie Lamport, based on TeX typesetting system created by Donald Knuth.` Inspired by `doncherry` nice answer.

Comment: I find it problematic to link to this site when mentioning TeX. This site didn't invent TeX itself, it should be linked separately with some explanation.