# How to acknowledge LaTeX and its community in a report/manuscript/dissertation/book?

Tags: formatting, titles

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is best way to mention that a document has been typeset with TeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63468/what-is-best-way-to-mention-that-a-document-has-been-typeset-with-tex)

I did my thesis with LaTeX, even the figures, they were all done with `TikZ` !! I would like to acknowledge the community in some way in my report. I would like to have some inspiring ideas from the community, I suppose that many of you have already done it. Is there a traditional way to do so?

Something in the lines of:

This thesis was typeset with LaTeX using a modified version of `scrreprt` class. Figures where done/typeset with `tikz`. Many Ideas where taken from www.tex.stackexchange.com, etc..

Should I put it in the back of the title page? in the acknowledgement page?

Of course I would like a solution ready made with `scrreprt` compatibility, but let us keep it as an open question so that it can be useful for others.

Comment: Related: [What is best way to mention that a document has been typeset with TeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63468/what-is-best-way-to-mention-that-a-document-has-been-typeset-with-tex)

Comment: Very good to think about this! Have a look at the question recommended by Marco. To keep all useful information regarding this together at one place, let's close this one and continue with the earlier question which already got some answers.

Comment: Seems fair to me. Thanks for pointing out the other question