# How to let the people know that my document was produced with/on LaTeX

Tags: presentations

I want to put a LaTeX "notice" in my document, something like "This document was *created using* LaTeX". However, I think the words in italic might be wrong: should it be "created", or "produced", or what?, and should it be "using", or "on", or what?

Comment: See [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63468/8528).

Comment: Well if you use the standard classes with ComputerModern fonts, you don't need to advertise it. In fact, the most of documents created with LaTeX look very *genenric*. But if you take a little more care about the layout perhaps you could advertise it. In books usually you can do it in the legal page or in the colophon. I don't understand what's the problem.

Comment: Thanks @jon, I will use "This thesis was typeset using the LaTeX typesetting system originally developed by Leslie Lamport, based on TeX created by Donald Knuth.". Just lets assume that someone does'nt know about LaTeX and that person does'nt get to meet me, it is a good idea to let them know how did I achieved such a quality.