# Why does line wrapping go wrong with l3galley cutout and ragged right?

Tags: line-breaking, l3galley

Why do I get a strange line break when using a cutout from `l3galley` with a ragged right paragraph? I would expect the break to come after *amet,* in the following MWE. Can it be fixed?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[width=170pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{l3galley}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\galley_cutout_left:nn { 0 } { 2em , 2em }
\dim_set:Nn \l_galley_line_right_skip { 0 pt plus 1 fil }
\ExplSyntaxOff
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think this might be related to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97808/unexpected-interaction-between-raggedright-and-parshape/98900#98900