# Creating CAPTCHAs and other fancy distorted letters with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I try to do a little more spectacular that phrase ( Δελτιο Υλης) . Is the headline on a press material for my students. The fact is that I could accomplish this with gimp or a graphics program such as the inscape or similar programs.

But what I want is to make a somewhat **artistic distortion of letters through tikz** to show to my students the possibilities of having the LaTeX without using external programs.

**My question:**  is there a way to warp letter and how?

Currently this is what I've done ... and certainly  I have not artistic vein ...

[image]

```
\documentclass[b5paper,svgnames,10pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[grid,step=0.5cm,gray,very thin] (-1cm,-1cm) grid (9cm,1.5cm);
\node[scale=5.,color =MidnightBlue ] at (0,0) {$\Delta$};
\node[scale=5.,color =MidnightBlue ,rotate=30] at (0.84cm,0.1cm) {$\varepsilon$};
\node[scale=5.,color =MidnightBlue,rotate=-15 ] at (1.3cm,0.0cm) {$\lambda$};
\node[scale=5.,color =MidnightBlue,rotate=+15 ] at (1.95cm,-0.2cm) {$\tau$};
\node[scale=5.,color =MidnightBlue ] at (2.5cm,0) {$\iota$};
\node[scale=5.,color =MidnightBlue ] at (2.6cm,0.4cm) {$'$};
\node[scale=5.,color =MidnightBlue ] at (3.0cm,0) {$o$};
\node[scale=6.,color =MidnightBlue,rotate=-20 ] at (5.3cm,0.08cm) {$\Upsilon$};
\node[scale=5.,color =MidnightBlue ] at (6.cm,-0.2cm) {$\lambda$};
\node[scale=5.,color =MidnightBlue ] at (7.cm,-0.1cm) {$\eta$};
\node[scale=5.,color =MidnightBlue ] at (8.cm,0) {$\varsigma$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I would use MS Word for this. It's naturally supported

Comment: @percusse What I want to do is advertise LaTeX  not the word ... :)

Comment: Did you see one of our greatest questions about Ctulhu and random rotations of letters here http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29402/3235 ? Or any other great answers on this site ?

Comment: @karathan: Looks like a CAPTCHA to me. Maybe it would make sense to rename the question to accommodate that?

Comment: @percusse No, I had not seen this question. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @CountZero how you propose to rename it?

Comment: You are using Greek mathematical letters. The minuscules are (as they should) in their italic shape. I recommend to browse the [{greek}](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/greek?sort=frequent&pagesize=50) tag on how to properly use Greek letters.

Comment: @karathan: How about 'Creating CAPTCHAs and other artistically distorted letters with TikZ'?

Comment: @CountZero perhaps it is a good idea.

Comment: Maybe I should add that I meant the terrible quality of Word math rendering that it comes this horrible by default if one uses Word.

Comment: Why limit the question to TikZ? (see [Why Metapost discrimination](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/3414/323))

Answer (score 41, accepted):

No claims to artistry or anything (you may, or may not notice that I've changed the text :-), also as it involves randomness sometimes it looks OK sometimes it does not:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\pgfmathdeclarerandomlist{fonts}{{\bf}{\tt}{\rm}{\sf}{\it}{\sl}}

\tikzset{
    distort/.style={
        rotate=rand*10, 
        yslant=rand/3, 
        xslant=rand/3, 
        xscale=1+rand/4,
        yscale=1+rand/4,
        execute at begin node={%
            \pgfmathrandomitem{\newfont}{fonts}\newfont%
        }
    }
}

% Need a special space because inside \node { };
% \ignorespaces and \unskip will remove spaces.
\def\bigspace{\hbox to 1ex{\hfil}}

\begin{document}

\Huge

\begin{tikzpicture}

% The basic idea is to create a node called 0
% then by maintaining indexes \i = 1,2,... and \j = 0,1,...
% it is possible to position the current node (called \i)
% to the previous node (called \j).
\coordinate (0);
\foreach \letter [count=\i, count=\j from 0]in {P,i,g,s, \bigspace  ,m,i,g,h,t, \bigspace ,f,l,y}
    \node [inner sep=0pt, anchor=base west, distort]  at (\j.base east) (\i)
        {\pgfmathrandomitem{\newfont}{fonts}\newfont\letter};

\tikzset{yshift=-0.75in}


% The opacity is stored in an array and accessed
% using the (undocumented) evaluate key.
\foreach \c [evaluate={\o={5,25, 100}[\c-1];}]in {1,...,3} {
    \coordinate (0) at (rand/4, rand/4);
    \foreach \letter [count=\i, count=\j from 0]in {P,i,g,s, \bigspace  ,m,i,g,h,t, \bigspace ,f,l,y}
        \node [inner sep=0pt, anchor=base west, black!\o, distort]  at (\j.base east) (\i) {\letter};
}

\tikzset{yshift=-0.75in}

% In order to get the same randomness (!) the random seed
% can be set to a fixed value. In this case the value is
% selected from the range 1-32768.
\pgfmathrandominteger\seed{1}{32768}
\foreach \c [evaluate={\o={5,25, 100}[\c-1];}]in {1,...,3} {
    \coordinate (0) at (\c*2pt,\c*2pt);
    \pgfmathsetseed{\seed}
    \foreach \letter [count=\i, count=\j from 0]in {P,i,g,s, \bigspace  ,m,i,g,h,t, \bigspace ,f,l,y}
        \node [inner sep=0pt, anchor=base west, black!\o, distort]  at (\j.base east) (\i) {\letter};
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: catchpa]

**EDIT:** Added some more randomness in an attempt to make it more fancy.

Comment: Really an excellent result. LaTeX and Tikz have a unique way to surprise me!!! and all of you with your codes

Comment: If you find a little time, would be easy to put a short comment on each line to explain your code

Comment: Is there any way to get the text that is displayed to make it an actual captcha? (Sorry, TeX n00b)

Answer (score 21):

Here is a solution that uses Metapost and ConTeXt (no font changes but randomized color and scaling):

```
\starttext
\startMPpage[offset=3mm]

picture lab;

numeric total_width, current_width;

total_width := 0;

for s = "H", "e", "l", "p", "\quad", "Γ", "Δ" :
   lab := textext(s); 
   current_width := xpart (lrcorner lab - llcorner lab);

  for i = 1,3,2 :
   draw lab  rotated (-30 randomized 60) shifted (total_width randomized 5pt, i*6pt randomized 2pt)
      if i = 1 :
        scaled (0.8 randomized 0.2)
        withcolor (0.8 randomized 0.1, 0.8 randomized 0.1, 0.8 randomized 0.2)
      elseif i = 2 :
        scaled (0.8 randomized 0.2)
        withcolor (0.2 randomized 0.1, 0.1 randomized 0.1, 0.8 randomized 0.2)
      else :
        scaled (0.8 randomized 0.2)
        withcolor (0.8 randomized 0.1, 0.8 randomized 0.1, 0.8 randomized 0.2)
      fi;
  endfor

   total_width := total_width + current_width ;
endfor


\stopMPpage

\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]

Comment: something went wrong as all three colors are light. One of them (in the middle) is supposed to be dark.

Comment: No, `context filename` is correct. But the colors are changed at random, so there is no way to predict the output.

Comment: Hmm... strange. I uploaded a bigger picture.

Comment: Yes. Indeed. I might try to re-install ConTeXt. Well, thanks for the answer. This is really helpful. +1 :)

Comment: Although I use LaTeX + Tikz... is a very good result and will be useful to users of   Metapost and ConTeXt

Comment: @karathan: The code does not use any ConTeXt sepecific features and will work with LaTeX + emp as well.

Comment: @Aditya  What is 'emp' . I do not know what is.

Comment: @karathan: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emp It allows you to embed metapost code in LaTeX.

Comment: @Aditya  I will try to experiment

Answer (score 13):

Without PSTricks.

[image]

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[a0paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\FPseed=0
\begin{document}
\foreach \C in {I,a,m,a,p,i,g,.}{%
    \FPrandom\Scale\FPeval\Scale{round(Scale*10+1:2)}
    \FPrandom\Rotate\FPeval\Rotate{round(Rotate*1000:2)}
    \FPrandom\Raise\FPeval\Raise{round(Raise*10:2)}
    \scalebox{\Scale}{\rotatebox{\Rotate}{\raisebox{\Raise pt}{\C}}}%
}%
\end{document}
```