# Command to generate captchas

Tags: typography

I am looking to use a command that would generate the distorted word "CAPTCHA" as seen in the title of this document [Understanding CAPTCHA-Solving Services in an
Economic Context](http://static.usenix.org/event/sec10/tech/full_papers/Motoyama.pdf) I have no clue how to do this.

all help or pointing in the right direction would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You may have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Regarding your question, have you seen http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/105966/creating-captchas-and-other-fancy-distorted-letters-with-tikz?

Comment: Indeed, that does seem the way to go. I will look into it and post my result If I get round to it before handing in the final thesis.

Comment: You might try emailing the authors of that article to ask what they did.