# Realistic handwritten document

Tags: fonts, formatting

Is there a template/package that generates **realistic** handwritten documents?

The font should preferably reflect an **average handwritting** (readable).

Letters would follow a handwritting style but would change very little each time.

**Has anyone got any news/updates?**

Comment: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29402/how-do-i-make-my-document-look-like-it-was-written-by-a-cthulhu-worshipping-madm

Comment: I always thought one of the advantages of printing was that I didn't have to deal with other people's handwriting or, indeed, my own!

Comment: @Nasser That question is about crazy fonts, and I quote: "I'd like to make these things look like they were scrawled by a gibbering madman". **I'd like something that is enjoyable by anyone who reads it, that seems personalized and not computer generated, but maintains an average style of handwritting so it's readable by all.**

Answer (score 10):

There is [HandLaTeX](http://code.google.com/p/handlatex/) that could do it.

**Edit:**
Beware, this package **does not include any font**, it just randomize the appearance of the text. Used with an handwritten-like font, it gives a satisfactory result.

Example, using the [Fountain Pen Frenzy](http://www.dafont.com/fountain-pen-frenzy.font) font:

```
\usepackage[]{hand}

\begin{document}
\begin{handpar}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, feugiat ad metus vestibulum at
eget. Condimentum est dictumst, quis cras congue et turpis, ornare
lacinia hendrerit platea in. Nulla est proin pellentesque hendrerit
nulla vitae.
\end{handpar}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Does it come with normal handwritting fonts?

Comment: @user2692669: The webpage says no.

Comment: This touches on a core aspect of this sort of thing --- it's dependent on the font --- there have been a number of fonts which have attempted to imitate the slight variation of handwriting, Beowolf being one of the notable examples: http://letterror.com/fontcatalog/fontfont-beowolf/. Zapfino does have some variation through character substitution along these lines as I wrote up in: http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb24-2/tb77adams.pdf

Comment: the above is very hard to read.  Why not use what is here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29402/how-do-i-make-my-document-look-like-it-was-written-by-a-cthulhu-worshipping-madm  "How do I make my document look like it was written by a Cthulhu-worshipping madman?"

Comment: @Nasser IMHO, the [original font](http://www.dafont.com/fountain-pen-frenzy.font) is pretty hard to read, too.