# Using multiple versions (allographs) of each glyph randomly

Tags: fonts, typography

I wonder if there exists any system to make LaTeX print different versions of each letter randomly. The idea is to make a realistic handwritten or typewritten document where almost every «a» is a bit different from each other. Are there any font with dynamic parameters, such as the thickness of each part, to emulate this way different pressure patterns in a typewriter, for example?

Comment: This won't solve the question, but might be interesting http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29402/how-do-i-make-my-document-look-like-it-was-written-by-a-cthulhu-worshipping-madm

Comment: There are fonts which address this sort of thing --- the prototypical Beowulf: http://letterror.com/fontcatalog/fontfont-beowolf/ --- the hot metal version of Mistral had multiple forms for the more common letters, but that didn't survive into the digital age. Zapfino does this using glyph variants and ligatures, see my paper on it: http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb24-2/tb77adams.pdf

Comment: Also see http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29425

Comment: @WillAdams, you'r article is really nice, but the point here is to find a free font. Maybe there are some with nice and several ligatures...

Comment: Or this one, in fact, @Thérèse: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134220