# mdframed parchment layout

Tags: tikz-pgf, mdframed

I have recently found a very nice example of how to create text boxes with a parchment-style layout:

http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/framed-tikz/

Also, here on tex.stackexchange, there are numerous samples employing the `framed` package to produce this kind of layout.

However, in my document, I am already using the `mdframed` package to typeset a different kind of frame/box. Is it possible to produce such a layout using the `mdframed` package as well? If so - how?

### Edit

I following the suggestion from [Werner](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5764/werner), I have played around a little and achieved the following:

```
\makeatletter
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing, patterns}
\renewrobustcmd*\mdf@tikzbox@tfl[1]{%three or four borders
    \path(0,0)rectangle(\mdfboundingboxwidth,\mdfboundingboxheight);% replace \clip by \path
    \begin{scope}[mdfcorners]%
       \clip[preaction=mdfouterline]%
            [postaction=mdfbackground]%
            [postaction=mdfinnerline]#1;%
    \end{scope}%
    \path[mdfmiddleline,mdfcorners]#1;
  }%
\newenvironment{parchment}[1][]{%
  \mdfsetup{%
    frametitlebackgroundcolor=none,
    innermargin=5pt,
    frametitleaboveskip=-\ht\strutbox,
    frametitlebelowskip=-\ht\strutbox,
    innertopmargin=10pt,
    innerbottommargin=10pt,
    tikzsetting={
      line width=2pt,orange!30!black!10, decorate, 
      decoration={random steps, segment length=2.5cm, amplitude=1.5mm}
    },
    everyline=false
  }
  \ifstrempty{#1}{%
    \mdfsetup{%
      frametitle={\fcolorbox{black}{white}{Handout}},
    }%
  }{%
    \mdfsetup{%
      frametitle={\fcolorbox{black}{white}{Handout: #1}},
    }%
  }%
  \begin{mdframed}[]
    \relax%
}{\end{mdframed}}
\makeatother
```

However, when I use `everyline=true` instead of `everyline=false`, the pagebreaks in my document change. Can anybody explain?

### Edit 2

I have finally found some time to revisit this issue. Please have a look at this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{etextools}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=2.5cm,bmargin=2.5cm,lmargin=2cm,rmargin=3cm,marginparwidth=2.5cm,headheight=15pt}
\usepackage{emerald}

\let\fancyfont\ECFAugie

\makeatletter
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing, patterns}
\renewrobustcmd*\mdf@tikzbox@tfl[1]{%three or four borders
    \path(0,0)rectangle(\mdfboundingboxwidth,\mdfboundingboxheight);% replace \clip by \path
    \begin{scope}[mdfcorners]%
       \clip[preaction=mdfouterline]%
            [postaction=mdfbackground]%
            [postaction=mdfinnerline]#1;%
    \end{scope}%
    \path[mdfmiddleline,mdfcorners]#1;
  }%
\newenvironment{parchment}[1][]{%
  \mdfsetup{%
    frametitlebackgroundcolor=none,
    innermargin=5pt,
    frametitleaboveskip=-\ht\strutbox,
    frametitlebelowskip=-\ht\strutbox,
    innertopmargin=10pt,
    innerbottommargin=10pt,
    tikzsetting={
      line width=2pt,orange!30!black!10, decorate, 
      decoration={random steps, segment length=2.5cm, amplitude=1.5mm}
    },
    everyline=false
  }
  \ifstrempty{#1}{%
    \mdfsetup{%
      frametitle={\fcolorbox{black}{white}{Handout}},
    }%
  }{%
    \mdfsetup{%
      frametitle={\fcolorbox{black}{white}{Handout: #1}},
    }%
  }%
  \begin{mdframed}[]
    \relax%
}{\end{mdframed}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{parchment}[Lorem ipsum]
\fancyfont
\lipsum[1-60]
\end{parchment}
\end{document}
```

Here's the list of issues that I would still like to resolve:

- The frame borders are sometimes "chopped off". I think this is related to the bounding box/clipping of TikZ, but I don't know how to resolve it.

[image: screenshot]

- I would like to give the whole thing a background image that is cropped precisely to the drawn border.

Additionally, it would be great if the baselines could be slightly curved and tilted to look more like handwritten script - but I guess I can figure out how to do this - perhaps like this: [Cthulhu document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29402/how-do-i-make-my-document-look-like-it-was-written-by-a-cthulhu-worshipping-madm)

Comment: There is an example that seems to be similar to what you're after listed in the [`mdframed`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mdframed) [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mdframed/mdframed.pdf) (Example 6).

Comment: Carsten, did Werner's link help you resolve this, or are there still open issues?

Comment: Paul, I finally found some time to revisit this. I've added the bunch of remaining issues to the original post (Edit 2).