# If you were to write beautiful letters, which typesettings would you recommend?

Tags: typography

The context is to have a letter to be sent to people you love, if it looks like manuscript, it would be perfect.

Also if they are already packaged for Linux distributions, it would hold be even better, free as in free beer.

Comment: You can look [here](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/calligraphicalfonts.html)

Comment: People you love? Then [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29402/how-do-i-make-my-document-look-like-it-was-written-by-a-cthulhu-worshipping-madm) surely not.