# Horror movie font (looking for an ugly font)

Tags: fonts

are you aware of any disgusting / dripping / gooey / horrible looking fonts for latex ? I have a presentation to give, and I'd like to write an ugly (as in very unoptimal and cumbersome) result I obtained in an equally ugly font.

The kind of font I'm looking for is a typicaly horror movie / monster movie font. You can get an idea by looking at this [link](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=dripping%20font&t=canonical&iax=images&ia=images) or [this](https://proxy.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.newdesignfile.com%2Fpostpic%2F2015%2F07%2Fscary-horror-font_355754.png&f=1&nofb=1).

Comment: How about https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29402/194703 ?

Comment: Thank you @Schrödinger'scat those fonts are a start, but not quite what I'm looking for.

Comment: @OlivierBégassat when using XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX you can use any font you find on the internet, for example the fonts in the result of the search query you provided in your question.

Comment: How about Comic Sans?  That is truly horrific.

Answer (score 7):

The Velvetyne Type Foundry’s libre and open-source Trickster (discussed in [Trickster, A Postmortem](http://velvetyne.fr/news/trickster-a-postmortem/)) hasn’t been seen nearly as often as most drippy fonts, and its subtlety and creepiness can be adjusted by your choices among its many OpenType features. For example,

```
% compile with lualatex or xelatex
\documentclass[x11names,14pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontface\tricks{Trickster Regular}[
  Contextuals=Alternate,
  StylisticSet=3,
  Color=Red4,
  Scale=MatchUppercase]
\linespread{1.4}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  This is a clue.

  And here’s another clue.

  {\tricks How frightfully bizarre a conclusion we now reach!}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

To my eye, that’s more disturbing (in a good way) than the usual horror fonts, with their mechanically uniform drippiness.

You may also be interested in [Pointu](http://www.kps-fonts.ch/de_gruppe4.html), by Klaus-Peter Schäffel. It’s more stabby than drippy, but it hasn’t been used so often that your audience will hardly see it.

[image: sample of Pointu]