# Is there a "secret-service" font package?

Tags: fonts

I have seen this font used in many aspects beginning in the mid 20th century where it was used for writing government documents perhaps those that we see written by intelligent services with a capital word like "CLASSIFIED" written on the front page. Another example where it might be used is for writing quotes or short statements for beautifying the text (kind of ironic lol).

Below is a demo of this font that I acquired online for Microsoft word :
[image]

Is there any LaTeX package for such font or alternatively a font that looks similar to this one?

Comment: you can use any font you are using with Word with lualatex or xelatex just use `\usepackage{fontspec} \setmainfont{your font name}`

Comment: perfect! thank you very much @DavidCarlisle

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29402/how-do-i-make-my-document-look-like-it-was-written-by-a-cthulhu-worshipping-madm?r=SearchResults&s=1|32.5314

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use any font you are using with Word with lualatex or xelatex just use

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{your font name}
```