# How to write "Half Blood Prince" in Latex

Tags: fonts

May you introduce me somehow to write this quote with its font in Latex ? I'm very appreciated.
[image]

Comment: Somewhat related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29402/how-do-i-make-my-document-look-like-it-was-written-by-a-cthulhu-worshipping-madm?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C15.7072